# logical error using copy constructor in c++

Tags: c++

In the following program my intended output is to display the list of item a customer object is interested of but it is showing null values. no values are printed when i am calling showitem(). please help me out to correct the logical fault in my code.

```
class item
{

    int itemno;
    string name;
public:
    item()
    {
        itemno=0;
    }
    item(int r,string n)
    {
        itemno = r;
        name = n;
    }
    void showitem()
    {
        cout<<"Item no is:"<<itemno<<"\n";
        cout<<"Name is :"<<name<<"\n";
    }
};

class customer
{
public:
    int customerno;
    string customername;
    string address;
    int totalitem;
    item *iteminterested;

    customer()
    {
        iteminterested=0;
        totalitem=0;
    }
    customer(customer &custref)
    {
        customerno=custref.customerno;
        customername=custref.customername;
        address=custref.address;
        iteminterested=new item[custref.totalitem];
        for(int i=0;i<custref.totalitem;++i)
        {
            iteminterested[i]=custref.iteminterested[i];
        }
        totalitem=custref.totalitem;
    }
    customer(int no,string cusname,string add,item *temp,int total)
    {
        customerno=no;
        customername=cusname;
        address=add;
        iteminterested=new item[total];

        for(int i=0;i<totalitem;++i)
        {
            iteminterested[i]=temp[i];
        }
        totalitem=total;
    }
    void showcustomer()
    {
        cout<<"customer name is"<<customername<<"\n";
        cout<<"customer number is"<<customerno<<"\n";
        cout<<"customer address is"<<address<<"\n";
        cout<<"customer " <<customername <<"intersted in \n";
        for(int k=0;k<totalitem;k++)
        {
            iteminterested[k].showitem();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    customer steve;
    item itemarray[]={item(3,"sandwiches"),item(4,"paperbags"),item(5,"biscuits"),item(6,"coke"),item(10,"biscuits"),item(9,"pen"),item(1,"pencil"),item(2,"eraser")};
    steve=customer(2,"steve","aus",itemarray,5);
    steve.showcustomer();
    customer mark(steve);
    mark.showcustomer();
    mark.showcustomer();
    steve.showcustomer();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please properly format and indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

In the customer constructor you must set totalitem before assigning the items. It is not initialized for the loop. Or use total for the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Item {
  int itemno;
  string name;
public:
  Item()
    : itemno(0) { }
  Item(int r, string n)
    : itemno(r),
      name(n) { }
  void showitem() const {
    cout << "Item no is: " << itemno << "\n";
    cout << "Name is: " << name << "\n"; } };


class Customer {
public:
  int customerno;
  string customername;
  string address;
  int totalitem;
  Item* iteminterested;

  Customer()
    :  totalitem(0),
       iteminterested(0) { }
  Customer(const Customer& custref)
    : customerno(custref.customerno),
      customername(custref.customername),
      address(custref.address),
      totalitem(custref.totalitem) {
    iteminterested = new Item[totalitem];

    for (int i = 0; i < totalitem; ++i) {
      iteminterested[i] = custref.iteminterested[i]; } }
  Customer(int no, string cusname, string add, Item* temp, int total)
    : customerno(no),
      customername(cusname),
      address(add),
      totalitem(total) {
    iteminterested = new Item[total];

    for (int i = 0; i < totalitem; ++i) {
      iteminterested[i] = temp[i]; } }
  void showcustomer() const {
    cout << "customer name is: " << customername << "\n";
    cout << "customer number is: " << customerno << "\n";
    cout << "customer address is: " << address << "\n";
    cout << "customer " << customername << " intersted in \n";

    for (int k = 0; k < totalitem; ++k) {
      iteminterested[k].showitem(); } } };

int main() {
  Customer steve;
  Item itemarray[] = {
    Item(3, "sandwiches"),
    Item(4, "paperbags"),
    Item(5, "biscuits"),
    Item(6, "coke"),
    Item(10, "biscuits"),
    Item(9, "pen"),
    Item(1, "pencil"),
    Item(2, "eraser") };
  steve = Customer(2, "steve", "aus", itemarray, 5);
  steve.showcustomer();
  Customer mark(steve);
  mark.showcustomer();
  mark.showcustomer();
  steve.showcustomer();
  return 0; }
```

Comment: What was the problem? What did the OP do wrong? What needs to be done to correct the problem. Just dumping fixed code isn't much of an answer and isn't likely to help other visitors to SO.

Comment: Ya absolutely correct, i am not able to understand the changes made by Mr Adam burry. Please Mr Adam try to help me to understand your edited code version.